# DrRacket plugin not displaying strings on MacOS

Tags: plugins, scheme, racket

i made a racket plugin that displays a string everytime the code editor goes on or off focus.

in Windows 10, an extra terminal-like DrRacket window opens up to display these strings, as the user interacts with the IDE.
However, I have now switched to mac, using the same plugin, the strings are no longer being displayed.
It'd be nice to display things, as I'm intending to work on a plugin.
How can I get a plugin to display strings? Here's the relevant code:

```
(define tool@
  (unit
  (import drracket:tool^)
  (export drracket:tool-exports^)
  (define focus-detector-mixin
     (mixin (editor:info<%>) ()
     (super-new)

     (define/override (on-focus on?)
      (display "DrRacket: on focus? -> ") (displayln on?)
      (super on-focus on?))))

   (define (phase1) (void))
   (define (phase2) (void))

   (drracket:get/extend:extend-definitions-text focus-detector-mixin)))
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be fixed by running drracket from the terminal, assuming that you added it to your environment variables, you can simply run 'drracket'.

Comment: On Mac, `drracket` is not in `PATH`. Probably the right invocation is `/Application/Racket vX.X/bin/drracket` where `X.X` is the version number.